# Hiding objects within UITableViewCell iOS 8 (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, show-hide

I have a `UITableViewCell` that on touch, expands (dropdown). The user is then presented with a selection of options. When the user touches one of the options I want to briefly hide all the options, show an activity indicator spinning, display a confirmation message (on success) and then collapse the cell back to normal.

I'm having trouble hiding any object within the custom cell. The following simple code doesn't work (this is the correct superview corresponding to the cell):

```
var customCell: MyCustomCell = icon.superview.superview.superview as MyCustomCell
customCell.myLabel.hidden = false
```

I have tried hiding/showing a variety of different objects but nothing works. I've even popped it inside `dispatch_async` to ensure it runs on the main thread.

Additionally, Xcode 6 beta tells me that `myLabel.hidden` is read only. This also happens for other objects. Is this no longer the correct way to hide something?

I've had a search around but had no luck in finding an answer. If someone could help me out I'd be grateful! Thanks.

Comment: nothing is popping out at me so instead: here's what I'd do: assign `customCell.myLabel` to a variable to make sure it's the type you think: `var label: UILabel = customCell.myLabel`. Then print the current value of `hidden`: `println(label.hidden)`. Next check if the customCell is still on screen (maybe the tableview has reloaded?) by setting a background color (or whatever will work in your case): `customCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Comment: Interesting.. I did what you said. Hid the label, it printed out `true` (correct), Show the label, it printed out `false` (correct). Updated the `backgroundColor` and it only updated visually after the cell was collapsing again (not right away - I put a `sleep(2)` after calling `backgroundColor`)

Comment: maybe try using [`customCell.setNeedsDisplay()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) to force a redraw?

Comment: no luck. All this code is in a method `iconPress(icon: UIButton!)` which is attached to the appropriate icon via `addTarget` during cell initialisation. It seems any updates to the cell are visible only after `iconPress()` has returned. Perhaps my setup isn't the correct way to do this?

Comment: oh... well yeah if you are blocking the UI thread (main thread), you're not going to see any UI updates ;)

Comment: @Jiaaro that's what came into my mind, but I don't get how I'm blocking the main thread? Does `addTarget` block it? What's the best way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of doing something like this would be to implement the UITableViewDelegate method `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to let you know when a row is tapped.

Then you can easily get and modify the cell

```
var customCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as MyCustomCell
customCell.myLabel.hidden = false
```

I consider the line `icon.superview.superview.superview` to be a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). The multiple superview calls makes makes your code fragile and likely to break if you ever change the view hierarchy in your cell.

Comment: Ha… of course, my debugging advice should have started with this ;)

Comment: The only reason I'm doing it this way is to separate it from the expand/collapse code within the delegate method `didSelect...`. I did think it could be that line, however I've tried using `CGPoint` to grab the cell. That didn't work either. I might try putting it all back in `didSelect...`